# What's causing this exception from AngularDart?

Tags: exception, dart, angular-dart

My Angular Dart (1.0/1.1) web project is throwing the following exception, but because it's thrown from within the framework and not from my own code, I don't know what's causing it.

```
The null object does not have a getter '_nextEvalWatch'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '_nextEvalWatch'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []

STACKTRACE:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#1      WatchGroup.newGroup (package:angular/change_detection/watch_group.dart:279:34)
#2      Scope.createChild (package:angular/core/scope.dart:361:51)
#3      Scope.createProtoChild (package:angular/core/scope.dart:376:23)
#4      _updateContent (package:angular/directive/ng_include.dart:46:41)
#5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:902)
#6      _ZoneDelegate.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:508)
#7      _onRunUnary.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:63)
#8      VmTurnZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:104:16)
#9      _onRunUnary (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:17)
#10     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:804)
#11     _Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:484)
#12     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567)
#13     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:448)
#14     _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:358)
#15     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:412)
#16     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:891)
#17     _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:501)
#18     _onScheduleMicrotask.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/zone.dart:127:45)
#19     RootScope._runAsyncFns (package:angular/core/scope.dart:924:25)
#20     RootScope.digest (package:angular/core/scope.dart:813:38)
#21     Scope.apply (package:angular/core/scope.dart:316:24)
#22     RootScope.RootScope.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core/scope.dart:768:12)
#23     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:895)
#24     _ZoneDelegate.run (dart:async/zone.dart:501)
#25     VmTurnZone._finishTurn (package:angular/core/zone.dart:168:21)
#26     VmTurnZone._onRunBase (package:angular/core/zone.dart:111:43)
#27     _onRunUnary (package:angular/core/zone.dart:122:17)
#28     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:804)
#29     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:712)
#30     _CustomZone.bindUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:738)
```

Here's my pubspec.yaml:

```yml
name: webatara
description: Web-based Confabulous client
dependencies:
  barback: any
  browser: any
  angular: 1.1.0
  web_components: any
  msgpack:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/danellis/dart-msgpack.git
      ref: master
dev_dependencies:
  template_cache_transformer: any
transformers:
  - template_cache_transformer:
      entry_point: webatara|templates/app.html
  - angular:
      html_files:
        - lib/templates/app.html
        - lib/templates/input.html
        - lib/templates/roster.html
        - lib/templates/space.html
        - lib/templates/space_list.html
        - lib/templates/alerts.html
        - lib/templates/rostermenu.html
  - $dart2js:
      commandLineOptions: [--show-package-warnings]
      environment:
        MIRRORS: 'false'
```

Comment: Maybe the transformer is not configured. Can you ease add your `pubspec.yaml` to the question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I should point out that this happens in Dartium, so this is before any transformer magic happens.

Comment: As far as I know the Angular transformer is also executed when run in Dartium. This is know bad behavior and there is an open issue. This breaks debugging because the debugger can't assign breakpoints to code lines when the code was changed by a transformer.